# Can you a line containing multiple points with their own "time" in MongoDB geospatial as a single line doc instead of multiple point docs?

Tags: mongodb

Assuming I have multiple points with a "time" property that make up a line, and I have multiple lines, each with their own unique name. Is there a way that exists in mongodb such that I can do a geospatial index, where my document is a "Line" that contains multiple points w/time for each point, all in a single document?

Or do I have to store each point and its own "time" property in separate documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider other facts as well to make an appropriate choice for the document structure:

- If in single document with array of points, is your overall size going to exceed 16MB doc size limit?
- Are the points added incrementally? If so, using single document with an array of points may cause lot of relocation of the documents causing higher disk I/O. Also this may affect the oplogs as well.

If you are using single document for each point / time, you may need to duplicate all the other information that the document may contain.

What are some of the access / data maintenance patterns in your application? These patterns should drive along with system limitations like the one mentioned above should drive your decision to make an appropriate choice of document model.

Comment: I just care about being able to perform efficient geospatial queries. i.e. based on "time" range and a box.